# Error with ASCII characters

Tags: pdftex, texlive, unicode, input-encodings

I have an apostrophe as in `educator's`, which is displayed as `eductaor&#39;s` and prevents TeX from generating a pdf.

I have used this as well:

`\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`

how can I fix that?

*(Edit by Speravir – included from comment by OP)*

I am writing the file with python like this with `open("mytable.tex", 'w') as out_f: out_f.write(output.encode('utf8'))` that `output` is displaying correctly in browser but its being written like that in file.

Comment: did you load: `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` ?

Comment: There's a few more things we should know in order to help you here. What is it that ›displays‹ the `&#39;`? I'm assuming you're referring to the editor you're using, as you say you can't produce a pdf. If so, which one is it? And if it's the editor, how did the (correct) apostrophe get there in the first place? You're saying you *have* that apostrophe, but something is turning it into `&#39;`. What is the acutal encoding your text file is using? If the text file is encoded differently from what you're specifying with `inputenc`, things are likely to go wrong.

Comment: @NilsL I am writing the file with python like this with `open("mytable.tex", 'w') as out_f:
            out_f.write(output.encode('utf8'))` that `ouput` is displaying correctly in browser but its being written like that in file

Comment: Your python script does produce html entities, at least `&#39;`. In the output file there is no more UTF-8 character then to be encoded. Compare Mike Renfro's answer instead.

Answer (score 1):

Not a real answer, just an attempt to narrow down the problem. I can't reproduce the symptoms with the following Python code (version 2.7.2 on MacOS X):

utfcheck.py:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

problemString = u'educator'+unichr(39)+u's and '+unichr(0xc3)

documentTemplate=r"""\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
%s
\end{document}
"""

documentContent = documentTemplate % problemString

with open('myfile.tex', 'w') as out_f:
    out_f.write(documentContent.encode('utf-8'))
```

myfile.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
educator's and Ã
\end{document}
```

Resulting pdf snapshot, after running through regular `pdflatex`:

[image]